# onClick move to next index v-for and render

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js, v-for

Im building a quiz component in vue, i have a v-for loop on my questions array. When clicking an answer i want to move the v-for index onto the next question.

Currently it shows all my questions, so i need to hide all the others until the correct answer is selected and then move the array on.

Im not sure if this is possible?

```
<v-card v-for="(question, index) in quizQuestions" :key="index" class="elevation-0" height="62vh" style="overflow: scroll">
<v-card-title class="text-h5 primary--text">Question {{ index + 1 }}</v-card-title>
<v-card-subtitle>{{ question.value.questionTitle }}</v-card-subtitle>
<v-card-text>
    <v-btn v-for="(answer, index) in JSON.parse(question.value.answers)" :key="index" class="elevation-0 mr-4 rounded-lg" @click="checkAnswer(answer.correct, index)" x-large>
        {{ answer.text }}
    </v-btn>
</v-card-text>
<v-row class="d-flex flex-column" no-gutters>
    <v-divider></v-divider>
    <div>Question {{ index + 1}} of {{ quizQuestions.length }}</div>
    <v-progress-linear height="3vh" class="rounded-xl" :value="quizQuestions.length"></v-progress-linear>
</v-row>
</v-card>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you need to wrap the `v-card` in a `template` tag, and add on the `v-card` an `v-if` condition to show only the question index which equals to the currentIndex.

```
 <template v-for="(question, index) in quizQuestions">
    <v-card v-if="index === currentIndex" :key="index" class="elevation-0" height="62vh" style="overflow: scroll">
      <v-card-title class="text-h5 primary--text">Question {{ index + 1 }}</v-card-title>
      <v-card-subtitle>{{ question.value.questionTitle }}</v-card-subtitle>
      <v-card-text>
        <v-btn
          v-for="(answer, index) in JSON.parse(question.value.answers)"
          :key="index"
          class="elevation-0 mr-4 rounded-lg"
          @click="checkAnswer(answer.correct, index)"
          x-large
        >
          {{ answer.text }}
        </v-btn>
      </v-card-text>
      <v-row class="d-flex flex-column" no-gutters>
        <v-divider></v-divider>
        <div>Question {{ index + 1 }} of {{ quizQuestions.length }}</div>
        <v-progress-linear height="3vh" class="rounded-xl" :value="quizQuestions.length"></v-progress-linear>
      </v-row>
    </v-card>
  </template>
```

And in the `js` create a state for the `currentIndex` and a function to go to the next question by increase the `currentIndex`.

```
data: {
  return {
     currentIndex: 0,
  }
},
methods: {
  nextQuestion() {
    ++this.currentIndex
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add computed property to display the active question instead of your v-for to display all questions and it should look something like this

```
data: () => ({
  activeQuestionIndex: 1,
  quizQuestions: ["#f00", "#ccff00", "#eee", "#0f0"],
}),
computed:{
  activeQuestion: function () {
    return this.quizQuestions[this.activeQuestionIndex]
  }
}
```

So you remove `v-for` and everywhere where you used `question.someproperty` now you will use `activeQuestion.someporperty`

And `activeQuestionIndex` incrementation you should handle inside yours `checkAnswer` function

Comment: Thank you Vojin, as i posted this question i actually done something very similar which fixed my issue! 

I created two separate variables in my v-for, so "v-for question in questions.slice(startIndex, endIndex)" and incremented these when the answer is checked, i think i will change to your solution, thanks!

Comment: @Ezr0 Yes you should probably change it to computed properties. They are more optimized and will perform better. That is why they exist.

Comment: @Ezr0 Also accepting and upvoting my answer would be helpful for me if you can do it